# Drawing on a pixel in blocks and diagonally

Tags: java, graphics

I've been working on this mini project to teach myself how to better use the graphical functions and nested loops in Java. I have achieved my basic goal with this project to be able to draw on a screen pixel by pixel in blocks and diagonally.

The basic idea is that it draws on the screen pixel by pixel in two different ways, one is diagonally and one is block by block.

I'm looking for any way at all to improve my program *without* implementing code very much more advanced than the code used in the program so far. I'm really looking for *any* improvements at all. A way to make it more compact, faster running, basically anything at all to make it 'better'.

```
    /**
     * @author Samuel
     */
    package main;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Draw extends JFrame{
    public static int width = 1280;
    public static int height = (width/16)*9;
    int x = 3;
    int y = 25;
    Color randomColor = Color.BLACK;
    public Draw() {

        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        while(true) {
            nextPixel2(); //Change to nextPixel() for block, nextPixel2 for diagonal
            g.setColor(randomColor);
            g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
            pixels++;
        }
    }
    //250000~ timer value = 1 Second/Pixel
    int timer = 1;
    int pixels = 0; 
    int xLock = x;
    int xStart = x;  
    int yLock = y;
    int yStart = y;
    int blockSize = 50;
    int changeColor = 5; //Diagonal change color
    int i = 0;
    public void nextPixel2(){ //Diagonal
        x--;
        y++;
        for(int i = 0;i < timer;i++){
            i++;
            System.out.println("Pixels drawn: "+pixels);
        }
        while(x < xStart || y > height){
            xLock++;
            x=xLock;
            y=yLock;
            while(x > width) { 
                xLock--;
                x=xLock;
                yLock++;
                y=yLock;
            }
            if(y == height && x == width){
                xLock = xStart;
                x = xLock;
                yLock = yStart;
                y = yLock;
            }
            if(i < changeColor){ 
                i++;
            }else{
            generateColor();
            i=0;
            }
        }
    }
    public void nextPixel(){ //Blocks
        x++;
        pixels++;
            for(int i = 0;i < timer;i++){ 
                i++;
                System.out.println("Pixels drawn: "+pixels);
            }
            while(x-xLock >= blockSize){ 
                x=xLock;
                y++;
                while(y-yLock >= blockSize){ 
                    y=yLock;
                    xLock+= blockSize;
                    x=xLock;
                    while(xLock >= width){ 
                        yLock+= blockSize;
                        y=yLock-1;
                        xLock=xStart;
                        if(yLock >= height){ 
                            y = yStart;
                            yLock = yStart;
                            x = xStart;
                            xLock = xStart;
                        }
                    }
                generateColor();
                }
            }
        }
    public void generateColor(){ 
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        float red = rand.nextFloat();
        float green = rand.nextFloat();
        float blue = rand.nextFloat();
        randomColor = new Color(red, green, blue); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Draw draw = new Draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Can you please add a description in your question about what your program does? We are all here to improve our code in one way or another, but what makes your question unique is what your code does.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I did mention in my text that the program "draw on a screen pixel by pixel in blocks and diagonally.". Do I need to describe in detail what each individual piece of code does?

Comment: Absolutely not. Just a generic description is fine. Sorry, it was just very easy to miss your description.

Comment: I'll make it clearer then.

Comment: Much better, thanks! I would love to take a look at your code, but I am unable to do that today. I hope someone else will take a look at your code shortly. Welcome to Code Review!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Naming**

Names of methods should describe the purpose they have. If a comment is needed to describe what a method does `//Change to nextPixel() for block, nextPixel2 for diagonal`, one should think about another more meaningful name.
What would **Mr.Maintainer** think at reading this code ?

> ```
> @Override
> public void paint(Graphics g) {
>     super.paint(g);
>     while(true) {
>         nextPixel2(); //Change to nextPixel() for block, nextPixel2 for diagonal
>         g.setColor(randomColor);
>         g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
>         pixels++;
>     }
> }
> ```

He would get the conclusions

1. I need to dig into the `netxPixel2()` method
2. Inside this method the value of `randomColor` and a location (defined by x and y) will maybe be changed.
3. What does the `nextPixel2()` do and why does it change 2 things
4. There is another method `nextPixel()` involved, and I need to dig into this too
5. This is a never ending while loop

**Decoupling**
As the pixel manipulation code only relies on a `Graphics`, there is no need for this code to be inside a `JFrame` extending class. You should better use `composition over inheritence`.

**Style**

The indention of the code can be improved a lot. Maybe some of this came from pasting here but for sure not this

> ```
> if(i < changeColor){ 
>     i++;
> }else{
> generateColor();
> i=0;
> }
> ```

Ok, let us dig into `nextPixel2()`

What do we see ?

Neither `xStart` nor `yStart` will be changed ever (after a quick glance into `nextPixel()`), so we should make them `final` and also give them a new name like e.g `xBorderPosition`

> ```
> for(int i = 0;i < timer;i++){
>    i++;
>    System.out.println("Pixels drawn: "+pixels);
>  }
> ```

This is just boilerplate code, as pixels isn't increased anywhere in the method, it stays at the initial value of `0`, this should be removed, also because the responsibility of this method does not involve output of any data, but manipulating some values.

**Algorithm**

The x value will be decremented and the y value will be incremented. This will happen until

`x < xStart` or in other words until `x == 2`. At this point `xLock` will be incremented, `x = xLock` and `y = 25 = yLock = yStart`.

or

`y > height` which will be true after `xLock == 699` so this will be the case we need to dig into

If the first condition is true and `xLock` will be incremented to `xLock == 699` we start again with `y = 25 = yLock = yStart` and `x = xLock = 699`. After some iterations of the `while(true)` of the `paint()` method we will reach at the entrance to `nextPixel()` with the values `x == 4` and `y == 720` and after incrementing and decrementing we have `x == 3` and  `y == 721`.  Se let us see what the following striped code will do then

```
while(x < xStart || y > height){
    xLock++; // now 700
    x=xLock; // now 700
    y=yLock; // now 25
    while(x > width) { // still false
        xLock--;
        x=xLock;
        yLock++;
        y=yLock;
    }
}
```

So the `xLock == 699` border doesn't change anything as `x` is still `<= width`. But what we see is, if `xLock` would reach the value `1281` then `x > width` will be true and something will happen.

`yLock` will be incremented by one and `xLock` will become `1280` and the `x > width` **won't be true** again.

So as there is always only one iteration, we can replace this `while` loop with an `if` statement. So if anytime `x > width` we need to increment yLock by one and set xLock == width. And as we set `x = xLock` we can check if `xLock > width` and assign then the `xLock` and `yLock` values to `x` and `y`

**Refactoring**

```
while(x < xStart || y > height){
    xLock++;
    if (xLock > width) {
        yLock++;
        xLock = width;
    } 
    x = xLock;
    y = yLock;
    if(y == height && x == width){
        xLock = xStart;
        x = xLock;
        yLock = yStart;
        y = yLock;
    }
    if(i < changeColor){ 
        i++;
    }else{
        generateColor();
        i=0;
    }
}
```

As we have seen `x == width` will only be true, if `xLock > width`, we can check `y == height` inside this if statement.

Refactoring again

```
while(x < xStart || y > height){
    xLock++;
    if (xLock > width) {
        yLock++;
        xLock = width;
        if(yLock == height){
            xLock = xStart;
            yLock = yStart;
        }
    } 
    x = xLock;
    y = yLock;
    if(i < changeColor){ 
        i++;
    }else{
        generateColor();
        i=0;
    }
}
```

If we look at the remaining while conditions we see, that after this condtions will be true the first time, neither `x < xStart` will be true nor `y > height` will be true. So there is no need for a `while` loop. To save an additional indention, we also revert the condition to be a guard condition. Additional we extract the check for generating a random color to a separate method `isColorChangeNeeded()`, rename the class variable `i` to `colorCheckCounter` and the `changeColor` variable to `colorCheckLimit` **which should be final also**. And finally we will rename the method to `assignDiagonalPixelLocation`

```
public void assignDiagonalPixelLocation(){ 
    x--;
    y++;
    if (x >= xStart && y <=height) { return; }

    xLock++;
    if (xLock > width) {
        yLock++;
        xLock = width;
        if(yLock == height){
            xLock = xStart;
            yLock = yStart;
        }
    } 
    x = xLock;
    y = yLock;
    if(isColorChangeNeeded()){ 
        generateColor();
    }
}

private boolean isColorChangeNeeded() {
    colorCheckCounter++;
    if (colorCheckCounter <= colorCheckLimit){ return false; }

    colorCheckCounter=0;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I agree with most things you said and I've now implemented most of it in my code, if you think of many more ways to improve the code or any smart feature that I should add feel free to let me know :)

Comment: @Samy Feel free to ask a [follow up question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765) with your improved code.